# Regex: Replace After first space with &nbsp; in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm making translateModel in PHP, It's will be return out in HTML

So, In Example code it just replace space with `'&nbsp;'`

```
preg_replace('/\s/', '&nbsp;', $myString);
```

But what I want is Replace After first space to so on (Not count first space)

Such as:

- `A B C &nbsp;&nbsp;D &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E`

Comment: can you share the input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace each whitespace in a streak of whitespaces excluding the first whitespace, use

```
preg_replace('~(?<=\s)\s~', '&nbsp;', $myString)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zl9PJe/1).

It will turn `A B C   D     E` into `A B C &nbsp;&nbsp;D &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E`.

Your `/\s(?=\s)/` look*ahead* solution will replace all whitespaces but the last one in a streak of whitespaces, as the positive lookahead requires the presence of the pattern immediately to the *right* of the current location, whole the *lookbehind* will look for a match to the *left* of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```
preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '&nbsp;', $myString);
```